# Form submission URL - with no "slash" in the `action` tag?

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, post, http-post

I've created a form with this action tag inside:

`action="/folder/"`

My common sense says that now I should create a directory named "folder",
and place an `index.php` file inside that would process the form.

But I'm not sure if that is the common way that this is done.

For example, google.com have this action tag for their search button: 
`action="/search"`

No slash at the end.

But in order for my form to work, I must have the slash or else the browser would not get to to my `index.php` file.

1. So how is it usually done?
2. Is it ok to make the form my way? any drawbacks?
3. In what way can I cut the slash from my form and still make it work? (maybe something with .htaccess?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I doubt very much they are using folders with php files instead them, they will be using a routing standard to make clean URL's

**"Clean URLs, RESTful URLs, user-friendly URLs or SEO-friendly URLs are purely structural URLs that do not contain a query string [e.g., action=delete&id=91] and instead contain only the path of the resource (after the scheme [e.g., http] and the authority [e.g., example.org]). This is often done for aesthetic, usability, or search engine optimization (SEO) purposes.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL) Other reasons for designing a clean URL structure for a website or web service include ensuring that individual web resources remain under the same URL for years, which makes the World Wide Web a more stable and useful system,[2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) and to make them memorable, logical, easy to type, human-centric, and long-lived.[3]"**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL

I noticed you used the PHP tag in this question, I have added a link to Symfony routing which might give you an idea how you could implement such a feature in your project.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

Comment: Do you think they are simply using this .htacess line:
`RewriteRule ^search?$ processing-file.php [L]` ? if so, is that the exact way to do it, without effecting routing of other urls?

Comment: maybe but I wouldn't like to say sorry, my above answer is my best guess though.

Comment: Also is there a reason why you are doing it with folders and single php files ? it would be hard to maintain.

Comment: what is the better alternative?

Comment: Take a look at the symfony link, it explains how you can get your desired functionality by using a framework